# Can I use figures from the sciki-learn manual for a thesis

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to reuse figures from the scikit-learn website/manuel in a thesis. I could not find information about possible copyrights.
Most figures can be reproduced using the added code. In this case I am not aware of the correct copyright laws.
Is it OK to reuse figures, when cited correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question.

***The package and the docs are BSD licensed so you're free to use the content in a publication.***

If you use scikit-learn, please make sure to cite the package https://scikit-learn.org/stable/about.html#citing-scikit-learn